# writing a loop that ends when every permutation has been tried

Tags: function, lua, permutation

I have a function which takes six octal (0-7) digits as an argument and returns true or false.

I would like to run a loop that tries every single permutation of the values 0-7, and counts the number of "true" returns.

something like:

```
function count_possibles()
local count=0
local a,b,c,d,e,f=0,0,0,0,0,0
while possiblepermutations > 0 do
    if compare(a,b,c,d,e,f) == true then count = count +1 end
    permute(a,b,c,d,e,f)
    possiblepermutations = possiblepermutations -1
return count
end
```

I've tried playing around with the examples provided in http://www.lua.org/pil/9.3.html but those are all about iterating over tables, not quite what I'm doing.

I don't necessarily care about performance, this function is to test the compare function I wrote.

Is there an easy way to loop something until all possible permutations are tried?

Comment: Do you mean actual permutations of chars '0' - '7', where in a permutation each char appears exactly once? Or all arrays of six octal digits are ok?

Comment: Also, the linked PiL chapter has exactly the function you need. You can put octal digits in an array and then pass it to the 'permgen' function to get the iterator.

Comment: I haven't thought of it that way, I believe you are right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The straightforward method would seem fine, given the stated requirements:

```
local count = 0
local total = 0
for a = 0, 7 do
    for b = 0, 7 do
        for c = 0, 7 do
            for d = 0, 7 do
                for e = 0, 7 do
                    for f = 0, 7 do
                        total = total + 1
                        if compare(a,b,c,d,e,f) == true then count = count +1 end
                    end
                end
            end
        end
    end
end
return count, total
```

---

Of course, this has nothing to do with permutations. I favored the conflicting requirement (as seen in the question asker's code) that the first parameters are 0,0,0,0,0,0.